# Can docker container call host syscalls?

Tags: docker, macos, input, simulation

I'm running a Docker container (alphine) on MacOS 11.6, there's a Typescript app in that container. I need to simulate and record input from Docker on host. Is it possible to setup Docker in a way that would allow my container to control host's input using node.js `osx-mouse` package, or by writing a Swift wrapper creating `CGEvent`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost certainly not possible.  In general Docker containers are prohibited from accessing the host display or other host devices.  Since Docker Desktop runs a hidden Linux VM, it's especially difficult: the display technologies are totally different and the VM layer makes it look like the container and host are on physically separate systems.

As a general rule, if you need to interact with the host display or any other hardware, it's much easier to run the task outside a container.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've thought, thanks.